# authentication about the apache activemq

Tags: java, authentication, activemq-classic

By now, I implement the authentication of apache activemq through the configuration file (activemq.xml) as this link shows: http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.3/amq_security/Auth-SimpleAuthentPlugin.html

But in this way, if I want to add more users, I have to change the configuration file and restart the server, which doesn't make any sense in practical use.

So is there any way I can add users without restarting the server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used JAAS PropertiesLogin to solve this problem. I can change username and password and also group information in other files, thus gaining control of authentication. The server doesn't need to be restarted to make changes work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be giving access to a number of users over time, the easiest way is to do it is to use an LDAP directory through the [JAAS LDAP module](http://fusesource.com/docs/esb/4.3/amq_security/Auth-JAAS-LDAPAuthentPlugin.html). Active Directory integrates well, as does Apache DS if you're not in a Windows environment.

Comment: What's the difference between the JAAS LDAP module and a CertificateLoginModule? I prefer CertificateLoginModule because it seems to be easier. By the way, do you have an example or tutorial about how to implement CertificateLoginModule? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that Apache ActiveMQ doesn't implement CertificateLoginModule. I can only use TextFileCertificateLoginModule instead if I want to use SSL.